# Pass a vector of pointers to function in c++

Tags: c++, function, vector

I saw many posts here but none of them explains what I'm trying to do.
I have the vector `vector <Car*> carVector;` and I want to pass it to a function so I can read the information of the objects in there.
The objective is to pass it and then I can use it in this cicle

```
for (i = 0; i < racetrack.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < nRaceTracks + 1; j++) {
        if (racetrack[i]->getNome() == info[j]) {
            size= racetrack[i]->getTrackSize() / 100;
            for (int c = 0; c < carVector.size(); c++)
                carVector[c]->chargeBattery(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Please show the function and what you tried.

Comment: `void Foo(vector<Car*> carVector) { ...`

Comment: You have to be more specific. There is nothing special by passing a vector  of pointers.

Comment: The function that is receiving the vectors is `void Campeonato::criaCampeonato(string* info, vector<Car*> *carVector, vector<racetrack*> *racetrack)` but I don't know if I'm passing the vectors in the correct way

Comment: Why are you are you passing a pointer to a vector? Pass the vector itself, either by value, or by reference (if you want the caller to see the change). You could also pass by constant reference if you don't want to copy or modify the vector.

Comment: BTW, The reason you are being downvoted is you did not post a [mcve]

Comment: @drescherjm how do I do that? I just want to be able to read the information from the vector in the function that receives it, not changing values.

Comment: Then you probably want const reference. The answers already explained that.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function you've mentioned, just pass the vector by value, reference or const reference depending upon the circumstance, like following:

- Value: 
  `void Campeonato::criaCampeonato(string* info, vector<Carro*> vectorCarro, vector<Autodromo*> *vectorAutodromo)`
- Reference: 
  `void Campeonato::criaCampeonato(string* info, vector<Carro*>& vectorCarro, vector<Autodromo*> *vectorAutodromo)`
- Const reference:
  `void Campeonato::criaCampeonato(string* info, const vector<Carro*>& vectorCarro, vector<Autodromo*> *vectorAutodromo)`

If you must pass it as pointer then you can just dereference it within the function to use it as an array as follows:

```
void Campeonato::criaCampeonato(string* info, vector<Carro*> *vectorCarro, vector<Autodromo*> *vectorAutodromo) {
  for (i = 0; i < racetrack.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < nRaceTracks + 1; j++) {
        if (racetrack[i]->getNome() == info[j]) {
            size= racetrack[i]->getTrackSize() / 100;
            for (int c = 0; c < carVector.size(); c++)
                (*vectorCarro)[c]->chargeBattery(500);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the snippet you gave in the comments, you are trying to pass in pointers. You do not want to do this. You want references instead:

```
void Campeonato::criaCampeonato(string *info, const vector<Car*> &carVector, const vector<racetrack*> &racetrack) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < racetrack.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < nRaceTracks + 1; j++) { // you will need to pass nRaceTracks in too
            if (racetrack[i]->getNome() == info[j]) {
                size= racetrack[i]->getTrackSize() / 100;
                for (size_t c = 0; c < carVector.size(); c++)
                    carVector[c]->chargeBattery(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```